# Why bot dont mention user?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have Discord Bot which have to mention user and send data before message.
My code:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new discord.Client;

const prefix = "!";

client.on('message', message => {

if (message.content == (prefix + "logs")) {

message.channel.send(message.author + " " + message.createdAt, {
        files: [
          "path to file",
          ]
      });
}
});

client.login('token');
```

I get output:

```
480059129793347586 Sat Jul 25 2020 20:12:15 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
```

Why bot send id but dont mention user?

Next question...

How can I change GMT?

Comment: I change message.createdAt to Date() but bot send same date.

Answer (score 1):

To mention someone you actually need their user ID. and send the following string:

> <@userID>

So, to mention the user, just do:

> "<@" + message.author.id + ">"

Comment: Thx. Thats works for me. Maybe you know how to change GMT in message.createdAt?

Comment: like make it more huam readable? or change the timezone?

Comment: change timezone

Comment: If that helped, you can accept the answer :D